# If/else Javascript statement returns opposite value

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a script that prints out two different responses if the current date is less than or greater than two dates (Expected Return Date) retrieved from a Google sheet. The two dates are the `2020-07-28` and `2020-08-28`.

The code is below followed by the logs.

What I expect to happen is that when `2020-07-28` is retrieved, then the message "Expected Return Date is earlier than <todays date>" and when `2020-08-28` is retrieved, then the message "Expected Return Date is later than ".

The message "Expected Return Date is later than <todays date>" appears for both even though both dates are retrieved correctly.

Interestingly, when I change the comparison to "greater than" then the message "Expected Return Date is earlier than <todays date>" appears, which is wrong again.

```
function sendEmail()
{
    var now       = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
    var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var startRow  = 1;
    var sheet     = ss.getSheetByName ('NC tracking')
    var numRows   = sheet.getLastRow()-1;
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
    var data      = dataRange.getValues();
    
    for (var i = 906; i <= 907; ++i) { 

        var row = data[i];
        ExpectedReturnDate = row[8].toLocaleDateString();
        console.log("The expected return date is " +ExpectedReturnDate);
        console.log("Todays date is " +now);
        if (ExpectedReturnDate < now) {                                      
            console.log("Expected Return Date is earlier than " +now);
        } else {
            console.log("Expected Return Date is later than " +now);
        } // end-if
    } // end-for
} // end-function
```

Log output below;

```
The expected return date is 28/07/2020
Todays date is 10/08/2020
Expected Return Date is later than 10/08/2020
The expected return date is 28/08/2020
Todays date is 10/08/2020
Expected Return Date is later than 10/08/2020
```

Comment: Strings are compares lexicographically. The JavaScript environment executing your code doesn't know you're comparing dates.

Comment: Thanks very much, I didn't realise until you mentioned it that I had converted my dates into strings by the .toLocaleDateString() extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to use `Date` wherever possible, and to format `Date` values values as a `string` (using `toLocaleDateString`) only when they're displayed to the user:

```
function sendEmail()
{
    const now       = new Date();
    const ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const startRow  = 1;
    const sheet     = ss.getSheetByName ('NC tracking')
    const numRows   = sheet.getLastRow()-1;
    const dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
    const data      = dataRange.getValues();
    
    const nowFmt = now.toLocaleDateString();

    for( let i = 906; i <= 907; ++i ) { 
        const row = data[i];

        const expectedReturnDate = row[8];
        if( typeof expectedReturnDate !== 'object' || !( expectedReturnDate instanceof Date ) ) {
            throw new Error( "Expected Date value in row[8], but encountered " + ( typeof expectedReturnDate ) + " instead."  );
        }

        console.log( "The expected return date is " + expectedReturnDate.toLocaleDateString() );
        console.log( "Todays date is " + nowFmt );
        if( expectedReturnDate < now ) {                                      
            console.log( "Expected Return Date is earlier than " + nowFmt );
        } else {
            console.log( "Expected Return Date is later than " + nowFmt );
        } // end-if
    } // end-for
} // end-function
```

Comment: Thanks c-smile and Dai. It works now after I removed the .toLocaleDateString() from the variables in the comparison (only in the output as you suggested). I hadn't realized I had converted the dates into strings but using .toLocaleDateString(). I also noticed you changed my var to const (even though the script still works whilst not doing this). Is this a correction or just good programming practice?

Comment: @Chris It's good (and modern) JavaScript practice. Use `const` to denote locals that should never change after it's been assigned, and use `let` for mutable variables that should only exist in the scope they were declared.

Comment: Thanks Dai, will remember this.

Answer (score 0):

Your date comparison should be done like this...

```
var D1 = new Date('2020-07-28'), D2 = new Date('2020-08-28');


if(D1>D2){

// whatever

} else {

// whatever

}
```

Comment: `if(D1.getTime() > D2.getTime())` is more safe.